# Ways to combine attr() method with the each() method that has a function inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery so this might be a very easy question for you guys. I have two methods that I want to combine, but one fo them has a function. What are some ways to combine the methods to condense the code?Thanks!

```
$('.item').attr({
    "data-aos": "fade-in",
    "data-aos-duration": "4000"
});

$('.item').each(function(index){
    var delayNumber = index * 100;
    $(this).attr('data-aos-delay', delayNumber);
 })
```

Comment: Just copy the first `.attr` call into the loop, except with `$(this)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can combine them is like this:

```
$('.item').each(function(index){
   var delayNumber = index * 100;
   $(this).attr({"data-aos-delay": delayNumber, "data-aos": "fade-in"});
})
```

We can turn the following:

```
$('.item').attr({
    "data-aos": "fade-in",
    "data-aos-duration": "4000"
});
```

into this line :

```
$(this).attr({"data-aos-delay": delayNumber, "data-aos": "fade-in"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`attr(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

```
$('.item').attr("data-aos-delay", function(index, value){
   return index * 100;
}).attr("data-aos","fade-in");
```